# On hover show feature information of features inside buffer ol5

Tags: openlayers

I have created a buffer when user enter radius. Points are selected inside buffer but I dont know how to show feature information of selected features.

Here is my code:

```
 var select = new ol.interaction.Select({
    style: pointStyle
 });

 map.addInteraction(select);
 var selectedFeatures = select.getFeatures();

 var feature ;
 map.getViewport().addEventListener("dblclick", function(e) {
// circleLayer.getSource().clear();
 // select.getFeatures().clear();
 if(feature!=null){
        map.removeLayer(featureRequest);
        vectorSource.removeFeature(feature);
        marker.removeFeature(featureMarker);
        select.getFeatures().clear();
 }

    var coordinate = map.getEventCoordinate(e);
    console.log("coordinate = "+coordinate);
    //add marker
         var latLong = ol.proj.transform(coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
        featureMarker = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(coordinate));
        marker.addFeature(featureMarker);
    //add marker
     feature = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Circle(coordinate, dist));


//GET CIRCLE EXTENT
    var ext = feature.getGeometry().getExtent();

    //SELECT FEATURES BEFORE ADDING CIRCLE TO PREVENT THE CIRCLE FROM BEING SELECTED
   vectorSource.forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent(ext, function(features) {
        selectedFeatures.push(features);
    }); 

    //ADD CIRCLE
    vectorSource.addFeature(feature);

    /*** jsts ***/
                var geom_select = feature.getGeometry();
                console.log("geom_select = "+geom_select);
                var pt = reader_wkt.read('POINT (' + geom_select.getCenter().join(' ') + ')')
                var jsts_geom_select = pt.buffer(geom_select.getRadius());
                console.log("jsts_geom_select = "+jsts_geom_select);

    /*** jsts ***/
featureRequest = new ol.layer.Vector({
 title: 'Filtered point Map',
  visible: true,
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    loader: function(extent) {
      $.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs', {
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          service: 'WFS',
          version: '1.1.0',
          request: 'GetFeature',
          typename: 'export:Ground_Control_Point',
         outputFormat: 'application/json',
          srsname: 'EPSG:3857',
          bbox: extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857'
        }
      }).done(function(response) {
            console.log("response "+response);
             features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(response);

             // extent_swe=vectorSource.getExtent();
            features = features.filter(function(el) {
                  if (jsts_geom_select.contains(parser.read(el.getGeometry()))) {
                    return true;
                  }
                });
                console.log("features "+features);
                 select.getFeatures().extend(features);
                // vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
      });
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
    projection: 'EPSG:3857'
  }),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
          }),
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#ffcc33',
            width: 2
          }),
          image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 7,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
              color: 'aqua'
            })
          })
        })
});

 map.addLayer(featureRequest);
 });
```

[image]

How to get information on hover of selected points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all map elements in OpenLayers 5 are rendered to canvas, the only way to get info about feature under mouse is by catching `pointermove` event on map and then checking with `map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, ...` if there is feature at mouse location.

Code below displays tooltip when mouse is over feature. It presuposes that features have `myId` property, but it can be any. Base for the code is taken from OpenLayers popup example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/popup.html.

```
<style>
  .ol-tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2));
    filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2));
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    bottom: 17px;
    left: -50px;
    min-width: 170px;
  }
  .ol-tooltip:after, .ol-tooltip:before {
    top: 100%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  .ol-tooltip:after {
    border-top-color: white;
    border-width: 10px;
    left: 48px;
    margin-left: -10px;
  }
  .ol-tooltip:before {
    border-top-color: #cccccc;
    border-width: 11px;
    left: 48px;
    margin-left: -11px;
  }
   .ol-tooltip p {
     margin-top: 0;
     margin-bottom: 0;
</style>
...
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="tooltip" class="ol-tooltip">
  <div id="tooltip-content"></div>
</div>
...
<script>
  ...
  var tooltipContainer = document.getElementById('tooltip');
  var tooltipContent = document.getElementById('tooltip-content');

  var tooltip = new ol.Overlay({
    element: tooltipContainer,
    autoPan: true,
    autoPanAnimation: {
      duration: 250
    }
  });
  map.addOverlay(tooltip);

  var featureId = '';

  map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
    var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature) {
      if (featureId == feature.get('myId')) {
        return feature;
      };
      featureId = feature.get('myId');
      var coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
      tooltipContent.innerHTML = '<p>You are over ' + featureId + '</p>';
      tooltip.setPosition(coordinates);
      return feature;
    });
    if (!feature && (featureId != '')) {
      featureId = '';
      tooltip.setPosition(undefined);
    };
  });
</script>
```